# struggling to override @media min-width css rules under wordpress

Tags: wordpress, media, css

I am attempting to override a @media (min-width:#) rule with css code included in the head of my document.

The CSS rule being invoked from the external stylesheet is

```
    @media (min-width: 1200px)
       .span9 {
              width: 870px;
              }
```

so why does inserting

```
    <style type="text/css">

    @media (min-width: 1200px)
       .span9 {
              width: 1100px;
              }
    </style>
```

into the head of my document not do anything at all? when I live adjust the rule in chrome element inspector it works just as you would imagine.

I understand that subsequent (smaller) @media (min-width:#) rules can take precedence if they are processed last but shouldn't this include in the very bottom of the page head be the final thing processed?

I would really appreciate any advice as Ive been messing and reading about this for hours and I can't make any headway. Thanks kindly for your time. :)

Comment: If you look at the source code of the live page is your style block before or after the style sheet ?

Comment: hi! the custom style block comes after the stylesheet in question is referenced in the head of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly possibility - have you tried adding brackets to your media query?

```
<style type="text/css">

    @media (min-width: 1200px){
       .span9 {
          width: 1100px !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: this was what I was missing, thanks so much! it worked straight away. Is it possible you could quickly explain how this is being parsed differently? I haven't encountered that syntax before.

Comment: Without the braces, there is no context for you media query. The opening and closing braces signify the beginning and the end of the rules to be applied if the media-query condition is met. Without them, your external stylesheet will take precedence

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `!important` into your css property so ordering precedence is not the case:

```
<style type="text/css">

    @media (min-width: 1200px)
       .span9 {
              width: 1100px !important;
              }
</style>
```

I haven't try it though.